# How to display data from JSONarray to a ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm fetching and parsing JSON data from an URL.

I would like to know how to adapt my code to display the data in a ListView instead of a TextView, because I need to manipulate the data to be able to delete and update records from the list..

I have the folowing code:

```
public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    String list = "";
    String dataParsed = "";
    String singleParsed = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://gonee.000webhostapp.com/Computadora.json");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";

            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                list = list + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(list);

            for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                singleParsed = "Id: " + JO.get("id") + "\n" +
                            "Marca: " + JO.get("Marca") + "\n" +
                            "Modelo: " + JO.get("Modelo") + "\n" +
                            "Precio: " + JO.get("Precio") + "\n\n";

                    dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity.list.setText(this.dataParsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: create List of pojo class and use that to update list. Use recyclerview instead of listview. you should find many similar samples on the internet

Comment: Async task is deprecated for Android 30.Avoid its use.